# Making changes to /etc/sysctl.conf

Tags: unix

I want to add this configuration to my /etc/sysctl.conf so it remains permanent.

kernel.sem="250 32000 32 16000"

Is the quotes (") necessary or not?

Lastly, What do the various numbers mean? 250, 32000, etc?

Comment: Is there a question here ?

Comment: sorry edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the kernel.sem is an option which modifies the semaphores mechanism in the system for the shared resource mechanism.

more can be read [here](http://kernelmount.com/content/view/81/9/) about it.

The values which are set are: (using `kernel.sem = 250 32000 100 128`):

max number of arrays = 128
max semaphores per array = 250
max semaphores system wide = 32000
max ops per semop call = 100

the quotes are not needed.

If the file keeps changing, boot a live CD and edit the file from a remote system.

you can use the `ipcs` command to check semaphore usage.

[here](http://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/semaphore/) are many examples available.

consult the `ipcs` manual for usage instructions.

the `ipcs -l` command is probably what you are looking for (testing).

Comment: how do I test to see if each of the values were set properly? Other than doing a grep on the sysctl.cnf of course.

Comment: edited answer, please check again.

Comment: @HenleyChiu Did I answer the question or not? Any need for improvements?